# HTML and CSS: Submenu display

Tags: css, html, netbeans

I need some help. I am working on this navigation bra that has a list of menu in it, and one of them is Award. Award has submenu that is hidden, and if I hover it, it submenu should be visible to the user. However, when I hover over the Award, it submenu not being visible to the user. I don't what I am doing wrong. I was hopping that someone could help me here, Please.

Here is my code

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("nav_sidebar").style.width = "142px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.height = "142px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("nav_sidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.height= "0";
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
    width: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 2px;
    background: #38424f;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 10px;
}



.sidebar ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

.sidebar ul li:hover {
 background:#f6f6f6
}

.sidebar ul {
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 background: #fff;
 padding:0
}

.sidebar ul li {
    
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

.sidebar li ul:hover 
{
 display: block;
}




.sidebar li a {
    padding: 5px 8px 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #4ba6c1;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}


.sidebar a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Admin</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="../src//jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="../javascript/Scritp.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body> 
        
        <div class ="side_nave">
                <label class = "nav" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</label>
                <div class="main_panel" id = "main">
                    <div class="sidebar" id = "nav_sidebar">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" onclick=
                               "closeNav()">&times;</a></li>
                        <li><a class ="active" href="#">Employee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Awards</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Certificate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Update</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sent Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="../Login.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targeting `.sidebar li ul:hover` to show the hidden `ul`. That won't work because the `ul` you want to hover is hidden - you can't hover the element if it's hidden. Instead, you need to target `.sidebar li:hover > ul` which means that when you hover a `li` it will show any direct child `ul`'s

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("nav_sidebar").style.width = "142px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.height = "142px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("nav_sidebar").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.height= "0";
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
    width: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    left: 2px;
    background: #38424f;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 10px;
}



.sidebar ul
{
 list-style:none;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

.sidebar ul li:hover {
 background:#f6f6f6
}

.sidebar ul {
 display:none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 background: #fff;
 padding:0
}

.sidebar ul li {
    
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

.sidebar li:hover > ul 
{
 display: block;
}




.sidebar li a {
    padding: 5px 8px 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #4ba6c1;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}


.sidebar a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Admin</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="../src//jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/Main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="../javascript/Scritp.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body> 
        
        <div class ="side_nave">
                <label class = "nav" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; Menu</label>
                <div class="main_panel" id = "main">
                    <div class="sidebar" id = "nav_sidebar">
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" onclick=
                               "closeNav()">&times;</a></li>
                        <li><a class ="active" href="#">Employee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Awards</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Certificate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Update</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sent Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href ="../Login.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even solve this without JavaScript:

```
<li><a href="#" id="awards">Awards</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
#awards ul{
    display:none;
}

#awards:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```